# Pen pressure to z axis(depth)

Tags: scripting, grease-pencil

I am looking for a way to draw in 3d space utilizing stylus pressure (ideally with grease pencil). I am trying to link the stylus pressure to the depth of the stroke points (instead of line width). I also thought this may be possible by first creating a variable width line and then translating the points based on line thickness.

What I'm hoping to achieve with this is line widths created using perspective.

I have done some python scripting but not in blender, any tips on what to investigate would be greatly appreciated.

Forgive me if this is answered somewhere, this is the first question I've had about blender that wasn't already thoroughly covered by the community already.

Cheers,
Old man G